# Sitecore 8 WFFM - Send Email on Save Actions Error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I added one web form(Get Our Newsletter ) using component from experience editor,Subscribe button Save Actions am using the "Send Email Message".
screen 1:
[image]

[image]

Screen 2:

[image]

In Web config File

```xml
<setting name="MailServer" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
  <!--  MAIL SERVER USER
        If the SMTP server requires login, enter the user name in this setting
  -->
  <setting name="MailServerUserName" value="info@xyz.com" />
  <!--  MAIL SERVER PASSWORD
        If the SMTP server requires login, enter the password in this setting
  -->
  <setting name="MailServerPassword" value="xxxxx" />
  <!--  MAIL SERVER PORT
        If the SMTP server requires a custom port number, enter the value in this setting.
        The default value is: 25
  -->
  <setting name="MailServerPort" value="587" />
```

and also added below code (or without ) of config file:

```xml
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
    <network enableSsl="true" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Setup in Web Forms for Marketers:
[image]
Still am getting following error, please any one  help me for this
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add GMAIL login credentials to the WFFM setup (and also port and enableSSL).

I did a blogpost about it a long time ago :)
http://intothecore.cassidy.dk/2012/05/email-confusion-configuring-smtp.html

Answer (score 2):

The issue is most likely that you did not remove the default host settings from the default Send Email Send Action, which is sets the host and from email out of the box.

Browse to `/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions/Send Email Message` and then delete the settings from the `Parameters` field.

[image: WFFM Send Email Action Parameters]

You will have to remove the send action from your form and then re-add for the changes to take effect though unfortunately (or edit the Raw Value of the Save Actions on the forms to remove them).

If you get other errors then check your Sitecore log files for more detailed information on why the error occurred and a stack trace.

Comment: Thank you jammykam,email working fine, my problem solved.